# Drawable resolution responsive layout-swxxxdp

Tags: android

How can I add a folder from resolution ?

for example layout-sw600dp/sw720dp/w720dp/w1024/h720dp/h1024dp

I think that is possible in this form : drawable-sw600dp  ?

If any form of responsive drawables exists, How to layout-swxxxdp ?

Please see [Official practice guidlines](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [This url](http://www.gravlab.com/2013/11/21/common-android-screen-resolutions-video/).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a [possible solution](http://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res)